# Problems when i using GetTextExtentExPoint to calculate the extent of a string

Tags: text, fonts, size

I created a font object and selected it into the device content, then calculate the extent of the string using WIN32 API GetTextExtentExPoint, but the extent i got is the extent while using system default font.
For example, when i using system default font, the extent of the string is 36 pixel width and 16 pixel height, and 72 pixel width and 24 pixel height while using the font i created. But, i always got 36 pixel no mater using system default font or the font i created.
What's the problem with my codes?

Codes:

```
HDC hDC = GetDC();
ATLASSERT(hDC);

HFONT _hFontTitle = 0;
HFONT hSysFont = (HFONT)GetCurrentObject(hDC, OBJ_FONT);
ATLASSERT(hSysFont);
LOGFONT lf;
if(0 == GetObject(hSysFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf))
    _hFontTitle = CreateFont(16, 12, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, FIXED_PITCH|FF_DONTCARE, _T("Fixedsys"));
else{
    lf.lfHeight = 16;
    lf.lfWidth  = 12;
    lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

    _hFontTitle = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    ATLASSERT(_hFontTitle);
}
HFONT _hFontContent = 0;
HFONT hSysFont = (HFONT)GetCurrentObject(hDC, OBJ_FONT);
LOGFONT lf;
if(0 == GetObject(hSysFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf))
        _hFontContent = CreateFont(12, 9, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, FIXED_PITCH|FF_DONTCARE, _T("Fixedsys"));
else{
    lf.lfHeight = 12;
    lf.lfWidth  = 9;
    lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    _hFontContent = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    ATLASSERT(_hFontContent);
}

SIZE sizeTitle = TextMetricsHelper::GetTextLayout(hDC, _szTitle.c_str(), _szTitle.size(), _hFontTitle);
SIZE sizeContent = TextMetricsHelper::GetTextLayout(hDC, _szContent.c_str(), _szContent.size(), _hFontContent);
```

While GetTextLayout is:

```
SIZE GetTextLayout(HDC hDC, LPCTSTR lpszText, unsigned int cbText, HFONT hFont)
{
    //RECT rcText = {0, 0, 8, 10};

    HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, (HGDIOBJ)hFont);

    SIZE textSize;

    GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, lpszText, cbText, &textSize);
    //GetTextExtentExPoint(hDC, lpszText, cbText, 0, 0, 0, &sizeOfTitle);
    //DrawText(hDC, lpszText, cbText, &rcText, DT_CALCRECT);

    SelectObject(hDC, hOldFont);

    return textSize;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the font you created can be used, whatsoever ? Can you draw something using your font ?

Comment: Ohh, it seens that the font can't be used, i change the lfHeight or lfWidth of the LOGFONT, and then, the size of the text is not changed. So, why it can't be used?

Comment: Are you sure the font you are requesting exists on the system ? And don't you have to specify mure parameeters in the lf variable. As I said, I don't have experience with creating fonts but that's what I would test.

Comment: I have fixed this problem using CreateFont. 
MSDN: 
The CreateFontIndirect function creates a logical font with the characteristics specified in the LOGFONT structure. When this font is selected by using the SelectObject function, GDI's font mapper attempts to match the logical font with an existing physical font. If it fails to find an exact match, it provides an alternative whose characteristics match as many of the requested characteristics as possible.
So...

Comment: Thank you for you help. Wish you a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about creating fonts and so on, but I notice that both your `CreateFont` lines assign their result to the same variable `_hFontTitle`. Is this the intention ?